# Setting targetSdk based on "Optimization Tips"

Tags: android

I see Google has added a new section called "Optimization Tips" in the developer console.

In it it mentioned I should set a targetSdk.  I currently only have:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

In  [their documentation](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html#android-versions)
they say:

`"You can set the app's range of targeted Android versions in the manifest file, in the <uses-sdk> element. In most cases, you can target Android versions properly by setting the element's targetSdkVersion attribute to the highest API level available."`

and

`"targetSdkVersion is declared with value 11 or higher (14 or higher is recommended)"`

My app works perfectly in all versions of android including tablets.  Based on what they are saying, even though my app supports version 7, and uses no features of higher versions - should I really be setting my target to the highest possible value (currently API 17).

At the moment I get a reasonable amount of downloads for my app so I'm not understanding the benefit properly - is it just an indicator to google I've tested it on higher devices (since its a full screen canvas app - colour scheme and menu style, changes are unlikely to have any effect for me)

(Btw, I do understand why someone might want to use a higher targetSdk, I'm just wondering if one should set it higher even if you don't need it)

Comment: There's a distinction between target SDK version vs. minimum SDK version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> should I really be setting my target to the highest possible value (currently API 17)

Yes. It'll improve the user experience on newer devices in various ways.

An example of this is that devices with virtual soft keys, i.e. the last few generations of Nexus phones, will show the legacy options menu button if you're not targeting at least API level 11.

There are several other things to mention, but I'm a bit short on time at the moment. In short: You should always include a target API and a minimum API level.

I'd highly recommend you read this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: Simple, answer - I'll set it to the highest.  I don't use the menu at all (or any higher features) so I'm not sure setting it higher will have an effect, but it sounds like it definitely won't hurt.

Comment: Think about textviews. If you remember, in Android Gingerbread there was that ugly text views with blank background and yellow borders. If you target your application to the maximum SDK it will automatically change your textView into ICS textView (Black background, bottom blue border). Trust me, Gingerbread TextViews look extremily old-fashioned now :D

Comment: @BruceLowe Yeah, there are quite a few performance improvements as well, so it's definitely something you should do :)

Comment: the menu button issue is even worse on devices that have real buttons without the menu key, like the HTC one X : http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/4/3220059/htc-one-x-one-s-menu-button-multitasking-option-coming . it takes a whole line just for a single button. i think they've added a feature to disable it somehow, but it's worth mentioning it. other reasons for using the latest targetSdk : GPU acceleration, newer style, newer classes and methods, new features (like the multi-line,actionable notifications),... btw, if you use a problematic class/method, Lint should warn you about it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a targetSdk version is like indicating that you develop with higher level APIs taken into consideration. As Michell points out, it would automatically take care of a few things.

On the flip side this would also 'imply' that you have taken care of handling any deprecated APIs/ behavioral changes of APIs in your code.

1. For instance, AsyncTasks used to be executed in a ThreadPool(Parallel execution) prior to API 11. And in APIlevel >= 11 the default mode of execution of AsyncTasks is a Single Thread, the tasks being queued up. Now when you target SDK >=11 you implicitly accept that your AsyncTasks are fine to be run on a single thread (No parallel execution).
2. Google Nexus Devices have a soft menu button(When you have implemented menus) on screen when you don't specify a targetSDK version. Now when you do specify a target>=11 you indicate that you are taking care of displaying the menu yourself.

There are a few things like these that you should be aware of. As suggested it would be better if you could go through the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html 
carefully and sufficiently test the app for any deviations after you specify the target.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the AsyncTasks. Both your and Michell's answer's seem both correct and clearly explained.  Sorry,  I can only tick one of the answers though, so I've gone with the first one - but many thanks!